# Why does magnesium bromide transfers from a carbon atom to nitrogen in piperidine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilic-substitution, heterocyclic-compounds, grignard-reagent

[image]

In this reaction, why does $\ce{MgBr}$ goes to the $\ce{>NH}$ group and form a bond with nitrogen by removing $\ce{-H}$.

Also where does the negative charge go?

Comment: To substantiate `@Safdar`'s comment further, in the Evans pKa tables (e.g., https://www2.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/index.htm), cyclopentane is estimated (section «-Benzyl») by a pKa(DMSO) of ~59, and pyrrolidine (section «-Amines») by a pKa(DMSO) of 44. Ammonia is listed by a pKa(DMSO) of 41. Thus, the differences are considerable.

Comment: Acid base reactions are more favoured here. N has an acidic hydrogen hence attack happens. So R-MgBr converts into R-H.

Comment: A better title would be, "Why does a hydrogen transfer from nitrogen to carbon in this reaction?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no step 1 and step 2 in this reaction. Both are consecutive and second one is fast because it is an acid-base reaction:

[image: Acid-base exchange in Grignard reagent]

Note that approximate $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of ring $\ce{C-H}$ and $\ce{N-H}$ are 50 and 40, respectively. Thus, as soon as Grignard reagent is formed, it exchanges relatively acidic protons of $\ce{N-H}$ fast (Remember, Grignard is also a strong base). To visualize the exchange process, I included schematic representation at the bottom of the image.

Comment: If the Grignard's reaction with the halogen followed by the exchange with the nitrogen-H, would it be reasonable to call the product of the first reaction the kinetic, the later one the thermodynamic product?

Comment: Buttonwood : I think the reaction rate depends on preparation of Grignard reagent in either way because it is the RDS. The proton exchange is much faster to my knowledge. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Mathew is correct. There is no step 1 and step 2. There is just an acid/base reaction as the "Grignard reagent" is formed. To say there is a second step is to say, in the reaction of NaOH and HCl, the first step is the formation of HO-H. True. And the second step is the formation of NaCl. I think not.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I recognize now that my argumentation was (too much) influenced by a recent re-read about kinetic / thermodynamic deprotonations and metallations on halogenated pyridines. So it isn't sensible to this line of thought on saturated heterocyclic substrates as this one here.

Comment: How did you create the picture ? Can you tell me?

Comment: @Soham Chatterjee: I used ChemDraw.